# is it possible to print static method?

Tags: java, object

```
class DuckPrivate
{
    private static int size;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    Duck d=new Duck();
    d.setSize(25);
    d.getSize();
        System.out.println("size of duck is "+size);
    }
    public static void setSize(int s)
    {
        size=s;
    }
    public static int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error cannot find the symbol getSize(),why i am getting this error,is it possible to print the static method.

Comment: You defined static `getSize` and `setSize` methods in DuckPrivate, but you are calling `getSize` and `setSize` methods of the Duck class. Does the Duck class have such methods?

Comment: I would guess that its not the `System.out.println` part that generates the error, but rather the creation of a `Duck` object. Does the `Duck` class exist? The class you show is called `DuckPrivate`..?

Comment: @Sankar : It is not advisable to access static method/attribute with object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Duck d = new Duck();` you are calling `set/getSize` method of `Duck` not `DuckPrivate` and note `d.getSize();` if exist will return the value which you need to store.In `DuckPrivate` you can simply call `setSize(25);` as it's static and just print `size`.